# Adding elements inside a typedef while taking care of the overall size of the struct?

Tags: c++, arrays, c, enums, typedef

I have a `typedef`'ed struct which currently looks like this:

```cpp
typedef struct Sys_Inject
{
   uint16_t num;
   uint16_t alternative;
   uint8_t  delay;
   uint8_t  thresh;
   uint8_t  reserved[2];
   BOOL32   state;
   options_select_t sel;
   uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;
```

I want to get rid of the elements `BOOL32 state;` and `options_select_t sel;` and define them inside the `uint8_t reserved[2]` array such that `reserved[0] = state` and `reserved[1] = sel`. `BOOL32` is defined in another module as:

```cpp
typedef BOOL32 (*FScallback_t)(uint32_t);
```

Also `options_select_t` is an enum and is defined as:

```cpp
typedef enum options_select_e
{
    TEST_DEFAULT = 0,
    TEST_CURRENT,
    TEST_SAVED,
}options_select_t;
```

What is the actual size of `BOOL32` in this case? Is it 32 bits? Also, is the size of the enum 8 bits for each element?

Note that `reserved` is an array with two elements, so it is 16 bits in total.  How do I fit the two elements `state` and `sel` in it?

Comment: What you posted for `BOOL32` is actually the definition for `FScallback_t`, which is a pointer to a function that returns a `BOOL32`.

Comment: Also, where does this come from?  It looks like it's part of some library, and if so it's probably not something you want to touch.

Comment: *"What is the actual size of BOOL32 in this case?"* [There is as yet insufficient data for a meaningful answer](https://www.multivax.com/last_question.html)

Comment: @dbush No it is fine to modify. I just want to put BOOL32   state; and
   options_select_t sel; inside the reserved[2] array.

Comment: How about: `enum { RSVP_BOOL = 0, RSVP_SEL = 1 };` and then either `ptr->reserved[RSVP_BOOL] = (mybool ? 1 : 0);` or `ptr->reserved[RSVP_SEL] = mysel;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable way is to just use the compiler's information:

```
typedef struct Sys_Inject {
    uint16_t num;
    uint16_t alternative;
    uint8_t delay;
    uint8_t thresh;
    uint8_t reserved[2 + sizeof(BOOL32) + sizeof(options_select_t)];
    uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;
```

Here's a program that statically checks that:

- the struct maintains the same size
- the [offset of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) the `per` member in the struct is the same after

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b2844dba1ced646)**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>

enum BOOL32 : uint32_t { FALSE, TRUE };

enum options_select_t {
    TEST_DEFAULT = 0,
    TEST_CURRENT,
    TEST_SAVED,
};

struct OLD_Sys_Inject {
    uint16_t num;
    uint16_t alternative;
    uint8_t delay;
    uint8_t thresh;
    uint8_t reserved[2];
    BOOL32 state;
    options_select_t sel;
    uint32_t per;
};

typedef struct Sys_Inject {
    uint16_t num;
    uint16_t alternative;
    uint8_t delay;
    uint8_t thresh;
    uint8_t reserved[2 + sizeof(BOOL32) + sizeof(options_select_t)];
    uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;

static_assert(sizeof(OLD_Sys_Inject) == sizeof(Sys_Inject));
static_assert(offsetof(OLD_Sys_Inject, per) == offsetof(Sys_Inject, per));

int main() {}
```

Comment: To account for any potential alignment padding between `reserved[]` and `state`, or between `state` and `sel`, I would probably use something like this instead: `uint8_t reserved[2 + (offsetof(OLD_Sys_Inject, per) - offsetof(OLD_Sys_Inject, reserved[2]))];` Or maybe use `std::aligned_storage` to help with the calculations.

Comment: This ony works because it just happens there was no padding between the 3 fields in the original structure.  But if there was padding, it would be (re)moved.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I'm aware of it. This is why I include the static asserts that verify

Comment: @RemyLebeau Like I said, I decided adding the static asserts was enough.

Answer (score 2):

`BOOL32` is *most likely* 32 bits, given its name.  But you did not show the declaration for `BOOL32`, you actually showed the declaration of `FScallback_t`, which is a pointer to a function that *returns* a `BOOL32`.

The size of `options_select_t` is *compiler defined*.  It *may* be 1 byte, or it *may* be 2 bytes, or it *may* be 4 bytes, etc.  There is no way to answer that without knowing what compiler you are using, and what options you are specifying when compiling the code with it.

But, in any case, `reserved` is only 2 bytes in size.  There is no way to fit `state` into `reserved[0]` if `BOOL32` is more than 8 bits, or to fit `sel` into `reserved[1]` if `options_select_t` is more than 8 bits.  Nor should you try.  Assuming you need to preserve the same size of the original `Sys_Inject_t`, you will need to *extend* the size of `reserved` to include the sizes of `BOOL32` and `options_select_t`, eg.

```cpp
typedef struct Sys_Inject
{
   uint16_t num;
   uint16_t alternative;
   uint8_t  delay;
   uint8_t  thresh;
   uint8_t  reserved[2 + sizeof(BOOL32) + sizeof(options_select_t) + any padding that was present between the original fields];
   uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
typedef struct Sys_Inject
{
   uint16_t num;
   uint16_t alternative;
   uint8_t  delay;
   uint8_t  thresh;
   union 
   {
        uint8_t  reserved[2];
        struct 
        {
            uint8_t state: 1;
            options_select_t sel: 2;
        };
   };
   uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;
```

or

```
typedef struct Sys_Inject
{
   uint16_t num;
   uint16_t alternative;
   uint8_t  delay;
   uint8_t  thresh;
   union 
   {
        uint8_t  reserved[2];
        struct 
        {
            uint8_t state: 1;
            uint8_t :7;
            options_select_t: 8;
        };
   };
   uint32_t per;
} Sys_Inject_t;
```

Comment: Wait what. That modifies all sizes and offsets. Why bitfields?

Comment: he wants both in reserved[2]. No other option

Comment: Ah, I see now how you misunderstood it. That's creative, but I think it's not what OP actually meant. Removed my -1 though - it's a fair but obtuse reading of the - amittably obtuse - question

Comment: @sehe it is questionable who misunderstood.